# create a sequenced animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to create a sequenced animation.
In the code below I have three animations. I want each animation to run for a duration of 2 seconds and it should follow the order of how the animations are listed below. So each of the 3 animations should run for 2 seconds.
Only one animation can occur a single time so the animation should take 6 seconds in total.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(box)
        box.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
        box.backgroundColor = .orange
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: (.pi / 2))
            self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: (2 * .pi / 3))
            self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: (6 * .pi / 5))
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a completion handler  to specify what should happen if the animation was executed:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: (.pi / 2))
        }, completion: {_ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
                self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: (2 * .pi / 3))}, completion: {_ in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
                        self.box.transform = self.box.transform.rotated(by: (6 * .pi / 5)) 
                    })
            })
 })
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate